Why does the the Democratic Party want Biden to quit when he's not that far behind in the opinion polls?
Top Democratic Party faces are publicly asking Joe Biden to step down, apparently believing he won't win the election against Trump.
However, in reality, he is only 4 percentage points behind Trump, not a comprehensive disadvantage at all.
Yes, I know, he has said a lot of problematic things, but the polls suggest that's not a problem for the public, so why is it a problem for the Democratic Party?
Besides, he has already won the Democratic primary. Although it is not binding(*), just revoking a collective decision would not look good for the democratic process.
(*) As far as I'm aware, this is common knowledge, but I will happily provide links if asked.

"Questions asking for the internal motivations of people ... are off-topic ..."

@JustMe That is not the internal motivation of people, that is about the internal dynamics of the Democratic Party of the USA. Well, probably. Another possibility that Biden has only a small chance to win, on some reason, even if he is not so bad in the polls.

It's surely all a gamble. With Biden chances for Democrats might be not too good (they might still win) and without not much better (Biden is seen as too old mostly, otherwise okay). Maybe they find someone else who is popular enough, maybe not. But surely they do not have to stick to the result of primaries solely on the basis of tradition. They could do something else instead. Why not.

@GraySheep You can't ask "Why?" without getting into internal motivations of the people making the decisions.

The polls still show it a close race and changing who is running this close to the election could make things much worse.

Even the premise is dubious.  You could take the title of the question and build the exact opposite argument:  given the doubts voters have about Biden, should the Democratic party ignore public opinion and apparently stick to their intent to keep Biden?  And, btw, given how much polls got Trump votes wrong in 2016 and 2020, -4% to him is far from a reassuring look.

Right now, you can be assured there is a lot of backroom wheeling and dealing to a) keep Biden or b) replace Biden.  How do you expect to get solid answers from people who aren't privy to these discussions?  Because the press itself seems to as speculative to what's really going on as anyone else.  Which is as it should be because the Dems need to appear unified behind Biden.  Either to the end, or till the 5minutes before they announce a change of plans.  This is a bit like the Q about the Conservatives keeping up a stiff upper lip.

Firstly you seem to have predicted the future and claimed the Democrats are definitely dumping Biden. Evidence please. But maybe it's not ignoring opinion polls. Political parties often have in-depth private polling. Can you prove they're genuinely ignoring polls and not considering other issues or weighing them against the polls.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Afaik it is about the popular vote. I think top party strategists use probably some weighted probability distribution in the undecided states. But it still shows, they are head to head. If it would be all right what his... situations look, he should have no chance et all.

I think, the cause of the downs was that the current democrat mainstream wants Biden to step down. At least its media says this. And this question was interpreted as an argument to keep him.

Should have been closed as a duplicate of https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/88303/why-call-for-biden-to-step-down-now/ rather than just like this, but it's not too late to fix that.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Yes it is too late. It was clear that you will soon start this.

Before the closure of the question, I quickly summarize my most likely explanation:

Democrat party top heads might try to implement their own personal agenda.
Having -4% in the public opinion is not enough, the important would be the weighted summary of the probabilities in the undecided states. They might have access much more detailed analyses, created for usage in the campaign, and these might show much more worse result.


Ext: now I think the real reason is very different:

It was clear that he won't be better even in the rest of the campaign, thus his disadvantage had grown and not decrease. He had no chance to rework that disadvantage. The reason, why there was no chance for him to do better, is that he is old.
Even this terrible debate could have became a nuclear weapon for the republican campaign.

While Kamala has a similar disadvantage in the polls, she at least has chance to rework it. And no one can say for her that she could not talk.
Another important matter is Pelosi's view: it is not only about the presidency, but there will be also a congress election, and the terrible presidential campaign could have leaded also to a seriously lost congress. If Kamala loses, she will likely lose only as an ordinary loss, and not with a disaster.

My problem with this answer is that, I think, very realistic but it is still only guess.
